# How to create a background to keep button on it using resource editor

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, resource-editor

I am new to work on resource editor i have created two buttons next and previous to change the page in my own created window using CreateDialog function and resource editor.

Now i want to create a strip which i will put at the bottom of my window and I want to put the two buttons "NEXT" and "PREVIOUS" on that strip and that strip can be coloured (not be white). I want to do so because right now my buttons are on the display of image on my created window and which looks odd so i want my buttons to appear on the colourful strip(just like as you can see for .pdf files preview on preview pane) .

Any ideas how to accomplish it ?? I tried to use "COUSTOM CONTROL" option from the toolbox and wanted to colour it and wanted to put button on it but when i run the programme i found that before i had an image display  at preview pane but now it is not working(i mean on putting the "COUSTOM CONTROL" on my IDD_MAINDIALOG the preview of the image don't work any more which was working before but when i put "MFC BUTTON" (just to check if it works or not ??)on my IDD_MAINDIALOG then it works(i mean there is no problem in dispaying the image on my window which had stopped working due to "COUSTOM CONTROL") )

So any ideas how to accomplish this strip creation ??

Comment: 'strip' is a toolbar? a dialog bar? what is it?

Comment: @ Marius ..bY STRIP i mean if you see in previewpane the preview of .pdf file at bottom you will see the button to change the page. and those buttons are kept on black/grey background(of the form rectangle) that i am calling STRIP. actually i have a display of image on my own created window and but my buttons right now are located on the image so i want to create any such strip and then i want put buttons on it and that strip i will put at the bottom. Understood what i mean to say ??

Comment: @ Marius one pore thing i want to tell you that write now i have display of the image on my window using CredateDialog() and using Dialog (IDD_MAINDIALOG) on that i have my buttons. so i want to create strip on this IDD_MAINDIALOG(which already contains my by two buttons). Have you understood my problem ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be easier to put the image inside a picture control rather than putting the buttons inside a strip.